# Configuration of database details based on environments in golang

Tags: go, configuration

Requirement:
Configure database connections based on environments (like QA, PROD) in golang.
For eg:

```
{"QA":{
    "host":"124.44.2.2",
    "port":"1234"
    },
"PROD":{
    "host":"125.65.23.64",
    "port":"1234"
    }
}
```

I can configure it in JSON / YAML, etc, but problem is when we build go, build file does not contain non go files.  Hence, when deploying builds into different instances, it loses configuration files.

Another solution, I tried setting config in go itself (by setting constants).  And then reading constants based on environment name passed as parameters.  But then in docker, parameters are passed after build file name, whereas in go , it can read parameters only if passed before build file.

Can someone recommend best solution?

Comment: There is no one "best solution", but generally your configuration doesn't include every environment at once; the whole point of a config file is that you can fill it with different values appropriate to the environment where it's running, so that you can ship the same binary and a different config file as needed.

Comment: See [The 12-Factor App "Config" section](https://12factor.net/config)

Answer (score 2):

You would not normally bake in the configuration for the runtime environment at build time. You want a built binary (or Docker image or whatever) which is generic and independent of the deployment environment. Any configuration for external resources should be supplied at runtime so as to late bind the configuration when the application starts up.

Consider third-party components which are freely available on the internet. They are written in a *generic* fashion which makes them suitable in not just your environment, but the environments of *anyone* who downloads them.

This approach requires that you have a mechanism to supply the configuration directives when you deploy the application into dev, test, production or similar.

There are several mechanisms you might use to achieve this. The following list is **non-exhaustive**:

## Environment variables

Define environment variables at the top-level of your application, and pass these in when spawning the application binary. For example, you might define the environment variable `DATABASE_HOSTADDR` and set this equal to the `host:port` of the desired database server. In your `main` method, or similar:

```
// Load database host address
dbHostAddr, ok := os.LookupEnv("DATABASE_HOSTADDR")
if !ok || dbHostAddr == "" {
    log.Fatal("DATABASE_HOSTADDR not specified")
}

// Do something here to use the value retrieved from the env var,
// splitting on the port separator (:) if necessary to retrieve
// the hostname and port number as separate values.
```

## Command line arguments (or flags)

You might use a library to parse the arguments supplied to the binary when it starts. So, for example, if your application has the name `somebinary`, you would invoke it using:

```
./somebinary dbserver:12345
```

or, if you use command line flags (as provided by Go's built-in [`flag`](http://godoc.org/pkg/flag) library, among others):

```
./somebinary --db dbserver:12345
```

Example using flags:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
)

var dbHostAddr string

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if dbHostAddr == "" {
        log.Fatalf("--db flag must be specified")
    }

    // Do something with dbHostAddr
}

func init() {
    // Bind desired flags
    flag.StringVar(&dbHostAddr, "db", "", "Database connection path, in format host:port")
}
```

Example using `os.Args`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        log.Fatalf("database host address not supplied")
    }

    dbHostAddr := os.Args[1]

    // Do something with dbHostAddr
}
```

## External configuration files (JSON/TOML/YAML)

There is support in Go for parsing config files in a variety of formats, and if not included, there are libraries for the most popular. If your configuration requirements are more complex, consider writing a configuration file and deploying this alongside the application.

Configuration management solutions, such as Ansible or Salt, will help here in defining your deployment process and infrastructure configuration in code and can potentially generate your configuration for you. If your configuration is simple and static, you might store it directly into source control and package it as build artifacts in your build process.